# Clothes Dryer not heating clothes correctly

Tags: dryer, washing-machine

I have bought a HOOVER VTH 980 NA2C-84 heat pump dryer 3 weeks ago, and no matter what program I choose my clothes won't get dry. it has worked at drying clothes before but not any longer.
it has the NFC Connected Hoover wizard app that has a 5 min program that checks the motor, filters, and inductor for any damage, it says everything is okay.
One thing to add, the dryer has a water disposal container that usually gets filled at the end of the cycle. it is not getting filled or having any water inside it since the problem started showing. 
Any idea what can be causing this problem? provided that I clean the filters and choose the right program?

Comment: This bit, "it has worked at drying clothes before but not any longer" confuses me. You've had it for 3 weeks. Was it drying clothes and now it's not, or has it not dried your clothes since you had it installed?

Comment: I assume that PI is referring to use by a previous owner. Is this correct? Also, have you referred to the installation instructions to verify that all system requirements are met?

Comment: Its a new product, no previous owner.

Comment: What i meant by has worked was that i tried using it several times before, clothes were drying okay. but now the program runs and ends and yet the clothes are still wet.

Comment: I did not see the PI reread several times. I haven’t worked on heat pump dryers but do a fair amount of heat pump work. Is the air in the drum getting warm ? Is the exhaust blowing air ?  My only guess if it’s not heating would be a loss of refrigerant since it sounds like the electronics are checked by the test. Sounds like it’s time to call for warranty service.

Comment: The clothes are getting slightly warm and the exhaust is blowing some air. it really weird to be honest, the clothes are getting heated and turned over and the exhaust is blowing air outside, but the clothes are still very wet.

Comment: I had this problem with a conventional dryer once before (two-hour dry times), and the problem turned out to be a faulty spin cycle on the washer, which left many times more water in the fabric. Has the dry time length changed? Maybe the moisture sensor is dirty or failing.

Comment: One thing to add, the dryer has a water disposal container that usually gets filled at the end of the cycle. it is not getting filled or having any water inside it since the problem started showing.

Comment: You have a warranty, right? You should really be contacting the manufacturer/installer about this.

Comment: This post was my last hope before contacting them, to be honest, I'm really not looking forward to 2 weeks without the dryer and technicians coming over.

Comment: Well, since dryers don't yet use barometric pressure to boil off water, the clothes have to get somewhere *near* 212F/100C in order to dry, which is definitely ouchy-hot, since human skin scalds at 140F/60C.   Expect clothes to get a little warm even if the machine is broken; simply from the heat of the parts of the machine which are working.

Comment: You should check to make sure the exhaust vent (the tube from your machine to the outdoors) is not clogged with lint.